# I need to add another table and field to this query how would i do that?

Tags: sql

pin = SELECT VIN_NO from WkVehFl where WkVehFl.REG=rof.REG,

Above statement is what i would like to add to the below....

```
select rof.branch AS 'Location', 
work_order = rof.ro_number,
rof.driver, 
rof.REG,
customer = rof.driver || ' - ' || (select if isnull(company_name,'') <> '' 
        then company_name 
        else name || ' ' || surname endif
        from contact 
        where contact.contact_code = rof.driver), 
wos.job_code, 
wos.DETAIL_LINE,
wos.STATUS,
wos.INVOICE_NO,
sales_type = case wos.type
    when 'W' then 'Warranty'
    when 'R' then 'Retail'
    when 'S' then 'Misc'
    when 'I' then 'Internal'
    when 'P' then 'Policy'
    when 'F' then 'Fleet'
    when 'E' then 'Excess'
    when 'B' then 'Project Billing'
    else wos.type end, 
opened_date = date(wos.creation_date), 
last_labor_date = (select max(date(finish_time)) from wkmechwk where wkmechwk.ro_number = rof.ro_number and wkmechwk.job_code = wos.job_code), 
days_open = today() - date(wos.creation_date)+ 1
from WkRoFile rof inner join wkothsub wos on rof.ro_number = wos.ro_number
where 
date(wos.creation_date) >={ts '2021-01-01 00:00:00.00000'}
```

I have tried a couple different ways of adding this but cant seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add another join for the `WkVehFl` table to the FROM clause, and add the `VIN_NO` to the SELECT clause?

See the two `-- HERE` markers in the query below.

```
select rof.branch AS 'Location', 
work_order = rof.ro_number,
rof.driver, 
rof.REG,
customer = rof.driver || ' - ' || (select if isnull(company_name,'') <> '' 
        then company_name 
        else name || ' ' || surname endif
        from contact 
        where contact.contact_code = rof.driver), 
wos.job_code, 
wos.DETAIL_LINE,
wos.STATUS,
wos.INVOICE_NO,
sales_type = case wos.type
    when 'W' then 'Warranty'
    when 'R' then 'Retail'
    when 'S' then 'Misc'
    when 'I' then 'Internal'
    when 'P' then 'Policy'
    when 'F' then 'Fleet'
    when 'E' then 'Excess'
    when 'B' then 'Project Billing'
    else wos.type end, 
opened_date = date(wos.creation_date), 
last_labor_date = (select max(date(finish_time)) from wkmechwk where wkmechwk.ro_number = rof.ro_number and wkmechwk.job_code = wos.job_code), 
days_open = today() - date(wos.creation_date)+ 1,
WkVehFl.VIN_NO -- HERE
from WkRoFile rof 
    inner join wkothsub wos on rof.ro_number = wos.ro_number
    inner join WkVehFl on WkVehFl.REG = rof.REG -- HERE
where 
date(wos.creation_date) >={ts '2021-01-01 00:00:00.00000'}
```